# Using apache mod_proxy_balancer to round robin load balance

Tags: apache, mod-proxy-balancer

Is it possible with mod_proxy_balancer to do the following:

- Main application server: IP: 192.168.1.1
- Secondary server: IP: 192.168.1.2

Main application server deals with all requests from the public DNS using apache.

Then using mod_proxy_balancer to basically say

```
<Proxy balancer://myapp>
 BalancerMember http://192.168.1.1/ loadfactor=1 # Balancer member 1
 BalancerMember http://192.168.1.2/ loadfactor=3 # Balancer member 2
 ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>
```

So in effect it is saying, Main app server can either deal with this request or it can pass it on to another server in the cluster?

Also, if I'm using https, then would I just set up each apache on each of the servers to point to my signed certificate and listen on port 443 then they would naturally just deal over https when mod_proxy_balancer passes over the request?

I know I could set up a test myself, but I don't want to mess about setting up two Ubuntu VMs if someone can give me the quick answer here! :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes it is possible, but it doesn't do what you said. It distributes 3/4 of the requests to the first server and the remainder to the second. See the documentation.
2. You should use AJP or HTTP out the back of the balancer, speaking plaintext to the backend app servers. The only SSL needed in the system is in the load-balancing Apache.

Comment: 1. Sorry that was a copy/paste issue, I didn't actually check the code I was copying! Thanks for the answer though